# Simple Dirac-Delta Integral

Tags: integration, area, volume, dirac-delta

What is $\iint \delta (ax^2+by-c) \, dx \, dy$?

I am aware of the translational and scaling rules, as well as $\int\delta (x) \,dx=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's ill-defined. The best you can do is take a continuous compactly supported $\varphi:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and compute :
\begin{align}
\iint \varphi(x,y) \delta( ax^2 + by + c) \text{d}x \text{d}y &= \frac{1}{b} \int \varphi\left(x,-\frac{c+ax^2}{b}\right)\text{d}x
\end{align}

**Edit** :
We can actually do better : the distribution $\delta(ax^2 + by +c)$ is positive and of order $0$, so it corresponds to a positive Radon measure $\mu$. In this sens $\int \varphi \text d\mu$ is well-defined for any measurable positive function (but it might be infinite). In particular, for $\varphi = 1$ the constant function, we get :
$$\iint \delta(ax^2 + by +c)\text dx \text dy = +\infty$$

Comment: If a distribution is compactly supported, like $\delta$ is, then the test functions can be any $C^\infty$ functions, like $\varphi(x)\equiv 1.$

Comment: The distribution (of $2$ variables) $\delta(ax^2 + by +c)$ is not compactly supported

Comment: It is of order $0$ though, so the test function can be continuous (as opposed to smooth)